# How can I obtain a Windows XP Professional license for research?

Tags: windows-xp, licensing

How can I obtain a Windows XP Professional license for research (legally)?

Comment: For testing purposes, Microsoft provides some [free virtual machines](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads). That could be an option.

Comment: Buy one? http://popular.ebay.com/misc-n-z/windows-xp.htm

Comment: windows 7 has a so-called windows xp mode which is done by virtual machine in virtual pc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through MSDN Academic Alliance (MSDNAA).

https://www.dreamspark.com/

Comment: Unsure why this was down voted. I believe this is the appropriate route to go.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can buy an MSDN subscription. It allows to download various versions of XP with required licenses. You won't be getting any support from Microsoft though for the XP OS'es that you download.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/buy.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/subscriptions/dd364988.aspx